# User Agent string in Firefox keeps getting overridden

Tags: firefox, user-agent

The user agent string in Firefox keeps getting overridden, meaning I keep getting warnings about using too old a browser on several websites.

If I check `about:config` I can see it's being set to:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:2.0.1) Gecko/20140923 Firefox/4.0.0; xs-LnUJyPQ8APQ;kLOkcH;
```

This has been happening for a long time, and I've updated several versions since it started, but it's still happening.

I can reset it in `about:config`, but it gets overridden again next time I start Firefox.

I've tried disabling all addons, but get the same result.

This is very annoying - any idea how I can stop this happening?

Comment: What's the `xs-LnUJyPQ8APQ...` at the end?

Comment: @Jan haven't a clue. If I had to guess I'd say it's some sneaky way of creating a persistent way of uniquely identifying my browser. Don't appear to have any malware installed tho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like there is something misconfigured in your profile or prefs.js. In Windows Explorer enter %AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox into the folder path bar at the top of the window.  You should then see one or more folders named with a string of seemingly random letters and numbers. These are your profile folders which store all of your preferences. With Firefox closed you can try renaming just the prefs.js file in these folders and then open FF. If that doesn't work,  move the folders themselves elsewhere. You will be then essentially starting with a fresh configuration for FF. Note however you will lose all of your settings (in prefs.js) and extensions (folders). This should work,  but if not you can always rename/move everything back.

Comment: This got me on the right track. I found a `user.js` file with a single line for `general.useragent.override` - I deleted this file. I then also deleted the line for `general.useragent.override` from `prefs.js`. Problem gone, and I didn't lose all of my settings!

Comment: I'm glad this helped and that you were able to track down the specific properties to change and not loose anything. It's quite mysterious to me why these didn't get updated from version to version.